# Burst Business Objects Report with Specific pages

Tags: reporting-services, business-objects

We have built a standardised Business Objects report with multiple pages. We are aiming to use just one reporting pack for all of our business areas, but it is argued that some areas do not need some of the data.

The reports will currently be burst to a SharePoint site in PDF format.

I need to know if it is possible to somehow pick and chose which pages to include in a report dependant on the values passed into the parameters.

For instance if the report were for a parent node, then include pages 1-5 only, but if it were for a leaf level report include all 10 pages.

I'm not very familiar with the capabilities of Business Objects, but have been advised so far that it will only export the entire report and that this kind of dynamic reporting would not be possible.

Interested to know if anybody has managed to do this or something similar in the past, if not we may be forced to maintain multiple versions of the same report.

Regards

Comment: What are pages 1-5?  Are they separate report tabs, sections within a report?

Comment: Separate tabs within the report.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to dynamically hide report tabs.

There are a couple of less-than-perfect workarounds:

If you schedule the document via a *Publication*, you can choose a specific report tab.  However, the options are simply "All" tabs, or one specific tab.

Within a report tab, you can dynamically hide blocks based on a value.  So, if you were to move content from several tabs into one, you could dynamically hide some of them in order to archive the desired effect.

Comment: Ok thanks, we had some to a similar conclusion and have decided that it may be best to burst individual pages and use .net to join them from there.